# Is Using WordPress Supplied WYSIWYG Advisable?

Tags: plugin-development, wysiwyg, customization

I have been considering using the  `the_editor` function to create WYSIWYG editors in my own pages. Is using the WordPress's inbuilt WYSIWYG editor in a plugin meant for general distribution advisable? Is it considered a part of the API that we can rely on to not change and break the plugin in future versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using the built in editor is the right way to do it. WordPress prizes backwards compatibility so the function should continue to work forever.